# Mongoose: Save a JSON with embedded documents, using schemas with references

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

everyone. I tried to save a JSON (RecordNameVersion) like this

```
{   "created":"2015-11-10 15:47:41.107Z",
    "id_user" : "01",
    "version" : "1",
    "RecordName" : {"status" : "1", "name": "Paul"}
}
```

In my node application I have this for the schemas

```
var RecordNameVersion = new Schema({
    _id : Number,
    created : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    id_user : String,
    version : { type: Number, min: 0 },
    RecordName : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'TaxonRecordName'}
});

var RecordName = new Schema({
trn_version : { type: Number, ref: 'RecordNameVersion' },
status : String,
name : String
});
```

When I try to post the Json, this error is generated.

```
"message": "RecordNameVersion validation failed",
"name": "ValidationError",
```

Is possible save all the JSON in one go? or is necessary put embedded the schema for Record Name?
I prefer different collections for RecordNameVersion y RecordName.

Or I should put the id for RecordNameVersion in the json for RecordName

Answer (score 0):

Your error in saving RecordNameVersion is telling you the value of field

```
RecordName
```

wants to be a Reference, not some actual object.  So synthesize its Reference as :

```
{
    "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("123456789000")
    "created":"2015-11-10 15:47:41.107Z",
    "id_user" : "01",
    "version" : "1",
    "RecordName" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("123456789055")
}
```

then the corresponding RecordName save could be :

```
{
    "_id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("123456789055")
    "status":"1",
    "name" : "Paul",
    "version" : "1",
    "trn_version" : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("123456789000")
}
```

Notice the value of _id fields across the two documents